# simulation platform in linux to implement algorithms of distributed OS

Tags: linux, algorithm, simulation, platform

I'm working on distributed os algorithms. I have written one algorithm on mutual exclusion. I have submitted the paper, the reviewer said that I have to run my algorithm on a simulation platform but they did not mentioned the name. Please any one suggest me any platform where I can run my program.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about simulators specific to operating system research, but there are certainly network simulators which you might be able to use for this purpose, for example those listed at http://www.brianlinkletter.com/open-source-network-simulators/ One prominent commercial network simulator was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPNET, which you will see has now been acquired by some other company.

Comment: is there any free tool? what I have seen OPNET is not free.

Comment: I believe that there are free tools listed from the link that ends open-source-network-simulators.

Comment: Is it possible to execute distributed OS algorithm in Network Simulator ?? 
because I have found so much functional similarity between OPNET and Network Simulator .

Comment: I have not used either. Looking at the documentation https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.26/manual/singlehtml/index.html and https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.26/models/html/tcp.html#network-simulation-cradle it appears to be a general discrete event simulator with a library for simulating networks and protocols so I would expect that you could use this, given enough time to code up your algorithm. I know of a project that attempted to use OPNET to work out bandwidth requirements for a proposed system. Eventually they ran out of time and ran rough calculations on a spreadsheet instead.